# Saving custom object to NSUserDefaults - can't set encoder and decoder methods

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, spotify

How would you be able to save a custom object to NSUserDefaults??

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(obj, forKey: "object")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

The object is of the SPTAuthViewController class in the Spotify iOS SDK, so I can't edit it to add encoder and decoder methods. How can I encode the object into an NSData object to store it in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: You would need to render your custom object down to a dictionary format

Comment: @bolnad how would I do this? NSCoding?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store custom objects into user defaults. You can only store "property list objects" (NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects).

In order to save a custom object to user defaults you have to convert it to one of those types.

You can make your custom object conform to the NSCoding protocol. To do that you have to implement the `init(coder:)` and `encode(coder:)` methods. (I believe that's the swift form of the method names - I've been working in Objective-C lately so my Swift is getting rusty.) How you implement those methods depends on your class. Typically you make multiple calls to `encodeObject:forKey:` to encode your object's properties.

Once your custom object conforms to NSCoding you can convert it to NSData using the `NSKeyedArchiver` method `archivedDataWithRootObject()`. You then convert it from NSData back to the original object using the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method `unarchiveObjectWithData()`.

### EDIT:

I just realized that you were trying to save a view controller object (`SPTAuthViewController` to user defaults. You should not serialize and save view controller objects. Controller objects should not be used to save application data.

Comment: I can't implement the init(coder:) or encode(coder:) methods in my class because the object's class is part of the Spotify SDK. So I can't actually change it.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the objects from Spotify for reference? Or do they already conform to NSCoding? Or do these classes have existing init methods that let you create and fully configure an object?

Comment: You need to figure out what state data you need to preserve from your `SPTAuthViewController` object, and save that, not your view controller.